# Как приводить пустые интерфейсы в go к разным типам?

Tags: golang

Как привести пустой интерфейс к string, bool, int и тд?

Comment: например так https://stackoverflow.com/a/50940347/10487940

Answer (score 2):

в Go есть [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions). 
`i.(T)`, где i - это интерфейс, а Т - это тип, к которой нужно прийти.

например,

```
var i interface{} = "hello"

s := i.(string)
fmt.Println(s)

s, ok := i.(string)
fmt.Println(s, ok)

f, ok := i.(float64)
fmt.Println(f, ok)

f = i.(float64) // panic
fmt.Println(f)
```

но лучше использовать switch-case,

```
func do(i interface{}) {
    switch v := i.(type) {
    case int:
        fmt.Printf("Twice %v is %v\n", v, v*2)
    case string:
        fmt.Printf("%q is %v bytes long\n", v, len(v))
    default:
        fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
    }
}

func main() {
    do(21)
    do("hello")
    do(true)
}
```

```
Twice 21 is 42
"hello" is 5 bytes long
I don't know about type bool!
```